# Excel IF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to combine multiple IF statements and I can't get it to work. 
What it should do is the following:

If X=0 and Y>0, return 10000 OR if X>0 and Y=0, return -10000 if neither do nothing.

I have 2 columns with 7000 rows and I want to calculate the fold change between the 2. I am doing that by

```
=IF(CA2<1;-1/CA2;CA2)
```

so that 0.9 turns into -1.1. However if you have a value of 0 you get a #div/0! error. I was hoping to work around by giving single regulated values either a +10000 or -10000.

Comment: You just need to include an AND in your IF: =IF(AND(X="0",Y>"0"),"1000","0"),IF(AND(X>"0",Y="0"),"-1000","0")

Comment: I still get an error when trying this.

Comment: I'm putting the formula like this: 
=IF(AND(BW2="0",BX2>"0"),"1000","0"),IF(AND(BW2>"0",BX2="0"),"-1000"‌​,"0") where BW2 is a number (but the product of a formule, which is the average)

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: "the formula you typed contains an error" and it highlights the ["0",BX2] part, I've tried replacing the , with the ; because the formula claims it needs that, but that also doens't help.

Comment: apologies made a mistake in the else if =IF(AND(A2=0,B2>0),1000,IF(AND(A2>0,B2=0),-1000,0))

Comment: =IF(AND(BW2=0;BX2>0);10000;IF(AND(BW2>0;BX2=0);-10000;0)) 

This works, apparently , need to be ; Probably a setting issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer should be to include an AND in your if:

```
 =IF(AND(A2=0,B2>0),1000,IF(AND(A2>0,B2=0),-1000,0))
```