# EXCEL IF FORMULA with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to put a remark using IF formula in column C below based on criteria:

```
A   B   C   
10  56% Leader
20  10% Laggard
55  45% Mover
90  90% Cashcow
```

Criteria:

```
Remark      A       B
CASHCOW :   >50     >50%
MOVER   :   >50     BELOW 50%
LEADER  :   BELOW 50    >50%
LAGGARD :   BELOW 50    BELOW 50%
```

I am trying to figure out with this IF formula but not working:
=IF(A1&B1>=100&50%, "laggard", IF(A1&B1>=50&50%, "mover", IF(A1&B1>50&50%, "leader", "cashcow")))

Can anyone enlighten me how to get it done?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel IF statement with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711873/excel-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: _"not working"_ is not a problem description; you should explain why it's wrong. Anyway, you just need to learn about the basic boolean functions like `and()`, `or()`, etc. - and how the `&` operator does not do what you think it does.

Comment: thanks for sharing, i am a bit confused because now got four criteria...

Comment: so just pass four conditions to the `and()` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't need an `AND` or `OR` just a couple of nested `IFS`.

If `A1` (*10*) is greater than 50 we know it's going to be either a *CASHCOW* or *MOVER* so we just need to check if `B1` (*56%*) is greater or less than 50%:
`=IF(A1>50,IF(B1>0.5,"CASHCOW","MOVER"))`

If `A1` is less than 50 then the *FALSE* part of the function is used to check if `B1` if greater or less than 50% and return LEADER or LAGGARD as required.

```
=IF(A1>50,IF(B1>0.5,"CASHCOW","MOVER"),IF(B1>0.5,"LEADER","LAGGARD"))
```

The order of your TRUE/FALSE is important here as you don't state what happens if either value is exactly 50.  The first part is saying `IF A1 is greater than 50` - if it's equal to 50 then it's not greater so the FALSE part is used.

Comment: thank you Darren, ya your code is working, too; thanks for sharing this :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should work -

```
=IF(AND(A1>50,B1>50%),"CASHCOW",IF(AND(A1>50,B1<50%),"MOVER",IF(AND(A1<50,B1>50%),"LEADER",IF(AND(A1<50,B1<50%),"LAGGARD","DO NOTHING"))))
```

Comment: Hi Ace, thank you so much, your code is working perfectly, finally solved my problem and improve my learning curve, appreciate your help!!